# Partial Isometries: Introduction

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

**Attention**

This question has been modified drastically.

It is done so the answer below is still correct.

It is done so to allow more specialized threads.

**Problem**

How do I deal with partial isometries?

How come that partial isometries give rise to projections?

And what about the that weird characterization given on wiki?

**Reference**

For more details see wiki's: [Partial Isometries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_isometry)

Comment: Since $ran(\Omega^* \Omega) = ker(\Omega)^{\perp}$, you're done.

Comment: For an operator-algebraic proof see: [Partial Isometries: Alternative Proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/614331/79762)

Comment: For an operator-theoretic proof see: [Essay: Partial Isometries](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~pskoufra/OANotes-PartialIsometries.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\Omega^{\star}\Omega$ is a projection, then it is an orthogonal projection. It is always true that $\mathcal{N}(\Omega^{\star}\Omega)=\mathcal{N}(\Omega)$ and, hence, $\Omega^{\star}\Omega$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\mathcal{N}(\Omega)^{\perp}=\overline{\mathcal{R}(\Omega^{\star})}$. Therefore,
$$\Omega^{\star}\Omega\Omega^{\star}=\Omega^{\star},\\
   \Omega\Omega^{\star}\Omega=\Omega.
$$
(The second follows by adjoint from the first.)
Likewise, if $\Omega\Omega^{\star}$ is a projection, then the same arguments apply as before where $\Omega$ and $\Omega^{\star}$ are swapped, which is enough because the last two expressions give the same two expressions when $\Omega$ and $\Omega^{\star}$ are swapped.

Note: It is convenient to think of a partial isometry $\Omega$ as a unitary map from one closed subspace $V$ of $\mathcal{H}$ to another closed subspace $W$ of $\mathcal{H}$. Then $\Omega^{\star}$ inverts $\Omega$ on its range $W$ and $\Omega$ inverts $\Omega^{\star}$ on its range $V$. That's why $\Omega^{\star}\Omega$ is the projection onto $V$ and $\Omega\Omega^{\star}$ is the projection onto $W$.

Comment: But is there also a check via the operators themselves not mentioning their ranges and kernels? I remember similar proofs for orthogonal projections $P$ where one could think of what their ranges and kernels do or alternatively how they relate to $\mathbb{1}-P$ which makes checks in many cases much more convenient (apart from intuition of course).

Comment: It's very useful to think in terms of a unitary map from one subspace to another, with 0 on the other parts. That really helps clarify your thinking about partial isometries, and helps in working with them. Orthogonal projections are easier. $I-P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement. In the previous problem I showed you have to think in terms of unitary on subspaces, and how to then see the inverses. It is a useful mental model because you're normally only concerned with the isometric parts. For example, showing two restrictions are unitarily equivalent.

Comment: Why is it always true that $\mathcal{N}(\Omega^*\Omega)=\mathcal{N}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Yes, for intuition it's nice to think in terms of subspaces... ...but for an actual (clean) proof?

Comment: @Freeze_S : $(\Omega^{\star}\Omega x,x)=\|\Omega x\|^{2}$ regardless of the bounded operator $\Omega$. So $\Omega^{\star}\Omega x = 0 \implies \Omega x=0$. Clean proof of what? I think I gave you a clean proof of everything you asked about here.

Comment: Ah ok. :) ....clean was only in parantheses as everything here is rigorous I just hoped for a straightforward manipulation like multiplying some operator from the left and some from the right or something similar. But that proof is fair enough!!

Comment: I know now what I was looking for: Is there an operator-algebraic proof rather than an operator-theoretic one? *(Sorry for the bad choice of phrasing "clean proof".)*

Comment: Ok how about this: I will open a new thread on the operator-algebraic properties of partial isometries. Same time I will turn this one into an operator-theoretic thread. This way your answer specializing on their subspaces fits best. However you or me might need to modify your answer then. *(The problem is that I'd really like to separate these to perspectives but the same time I don't want to destroy the validity of your answer.)*

Comment: **Please, you choose!** Or as a third idea I could turn this into an introductory thread and then open the other both more special ones. *(This way your answer with the extra note at the end would fit quite well.)*